# How to update an existing component every time a change occurs in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

so I am trying to build a sorting algorithm visualizer web page using Angular and have currently run into an issue. I am currently on bubble sort and am struggling with updating the array that is displayed on the page on initialization every time a swap occurs during the bubble sort. Currently I am trying to use a delay that every time a swap occurs in the sort, we wait for a certain delay but that still won't do it. I am still new to Angular so trying to figure things out as I go. Below is how I have my code set up:

[image: Text] ([![TypeScript file]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ahx7c.png))

[image: Text] ([![]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGM7w.png))

Feel free to leave any input you have, thanks!

Comment: What is ng-checked for?

Comment: @MikeOne i was trying to set a flag for every swap but wasn't working, removed that now

Comment: Oh and to answer your question, you really shouldn’t have to do anything special to update - Angular change detection is pretty good in doing that for you automagically. Unless you have set your component to onPush..

Comment: @MikeOne When I perform the sort the array does get sorted but the visual effect isn't there. I am trying to update the display on each individual swap but it gets updated when the entire array is fully swapped since the swap is completed almost instantaneously in code

Comment: I’s have to see the entire component to determine what is going on. You might have to ensure you’re becomes a new instance in every loop to have Angular pick it up. Probably an easy change and you can get rid of the delay code and so on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, the easer way is use timer from 'rxjs'. But we need first change the loop. We don't use for else while.

Step, by step. imagine a simple loop

```
for(k=0;k<10;k++)
{
   this.result=k;
}
```

This make that only show result 10

we are convert to a while

```
let k=0
while(k<10)
{
   this.result=k
}
```

Again only show the final result 10

Using a timer

```
let k=0
timer(0,500).pipe(takeWhile(()=>k<10)).subscribe(()=>{
  while (k<10)
  {
    this.result=k
    k++;
    break;
  }
})
```

Well, the problem is that we has two loop, and we want to use a condition, (In the example I put a simple condition)

```
let i = 0;
let j = 0;
timer(0, 500)
  .pipe(takeWhile(() => i < this.array.length))
  .subscribe(() => {
    while (i < this.array.length) {
      let change = false;
      while (j < this.array.length) {
        if (j == 2) { //<--yes is a simple condition
          change = true;
          this.result = i + "," + j;
          j++
          break;
        }
        j++;
      }
      if (change) break;
      if (j == this.array.length){
          i++;
          j = 0;
      }
    }
  });
```

Just change the condition according you meetings

Comment: Thank you! Using that structure I was able to get it working as I wanted it to!